# Differences between cloudant service created directly on cloudant.com versus through Bluemix

Tags: comparison, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I created a cloudant service and database through Bluemix initially.  I'm not certain how I found my way to that path.  Everything went well save the fact that the simplicity of a username.cloudant.com access that had been part of a "how to" I was following didn't exist.  My service was named with a UID.  I can see how I can create something friendly through a virtual host, but I am still a little confused about how to create a more user friendly password for access to said database.

I went back and found that I could create another cloudant service directly at cloudant.com.  True to the "how to" I can now access via username.cloudant.com and the user friendly password I created the account with.

What are the differences and advantages/disadvantages of my two different cloudant services??

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This question is probably a bit broad for stackoverflow and it may get flagged to be closed. See the help center about what constitutes a good question.

Answer (score 3):

This question is a bit broad for stackoverflow so I will answer as a community wiki so others can contribute to the answer:

- cloudant on bluemix has provisioned capacity - you can read about it here https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2016/09/new-cloudant-lite-standard-plans-are-live-in-bluemix-public/.  This helps to overcome the effects of noisy neighbours on shared plans.
- cloudant on bluemix is great if you are developing applications for bluemix because linked applications get access to the credentials for cloudant so you dont have to hard code the credentials into your application

Hopefully others will add their thoughts above.